# sqlite3.dll already exists under the filter

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm getting the error sqlite3.dll already exists under the filter when loading a newly built solution in Unity using ILL2CPP.  This prevents my main project and the Unity Data project from loading.  If I go into the project files and delete the reference as well as delete the dll from the directory both projects load correctly and my app deploys to the Hololens Emulator fine.

I do see a reference to the dll in C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity

I'm not using Mono to build as mentioned, I'm using IL2CPP.  Why is this reference getting copied, what is it for and why is the error happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved, I had sqlite3.dll in multiple directories in my assets folder.  Deleting one of the dlls solved the issue.